# Pass through XML from another website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, xml, html

I am trying to pass through some XML from an external website.

What is the best way of doing this, through c# webpage or asp.MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use something like this for working with external XML documents / RSS feeds etc:

```
string sURL = ".....";
// Create a request for the URL. 
WebRequest oRequest = WebRequest.Create(sUrl);
// Get the response.
WebResponse oResponse = oRequest.GetResponse();
// Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
Stream oDataStream = oResponse.GetResponseStream();
// Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
StreamReader oReader = new StreamReader(oDataStream, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
// Read the content.
string sXML = oReader.ReadToEnd();
// Convert string to XML
XDocument oFeed = XDocument.Parse(sXML);
```

Comment: var myWebClient = new WebClient();
var stream = myWebClient.OpenRead("URL");

if (stream != null)
{
var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
var textXml = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

                this.Response.Clear();
                this.Response.ClearContent();
                this.Response.ClearHeaders();
                this.Response.Buffer = true;
                this.Response.BufferOutput = true;
                this.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
                this.Response.Write(textXml);
            }
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();

Answer (score 0):

Either should be fine. MVC is probably *easiest* (in terms of getting a raw response), but you could do the same in regular ASP.NET just by using a handler (possibly .ashx), or just by clearing the response.